# How to enable Flash plugin Programmatically in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, flash, plugins

Since Adobe will stop providing support for Flash after December 2020 and currently the chrome browser has blocked the Flash plugin. I have using the flash plugin in my application and want to enable the flash plugin through the .net code. I mean, similar to setting cookies. Below is the code for reference:

```
 void Application_AuthorizeRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

     HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[DemoAxis.AspNet.Security.DemoAxisAuthentication.CookieName.ToUpper()];

        if (Request.Browser.Browser == "Chrome")
        {
            //here i need to write some code to enable flash plugin
            cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            cookie.Secure = true;
        } 
 }
```

However, I can manually enable it by going through the setting tab of chrome and change it from block to allow.

Just wanted to know if there is anything I can do to set it to enable through code in the same way as we set cookies.

Thanks,

Comment: and now imagine a nefarious server just randomly, remotely enabling the flash plugin, loading a flash file, exploiting one of the many, many, many, many security problems flash has, and infecting your computer without you having the option to interveine... no, it is not possible, and it **should not** be possible. your best bet (and the only sane way) would be to stop using outdated technology (that wasn't even that great to begin with)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann the application is 25 years old. and by just a click we cannot remove the same..

Comment: If you never starts to reengineering it, you will never have a new one! Is your app in www or intranet? If only in intranet, you can use an older browser, but that is not recommended.

Comment: :@FranzGleichmann Finally.. Yes, Browser plugins need to go. It's just better that way (a website should not have a depency on some other external software).

Comment: This .net stuff really freaks me out..A data scientist forced to work on .net stack bcoz of this Covid. :(